# Add number to variable size in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to find the size of a folder, and add 1M to it. The 1M is just spacing that I need for other reasons.

Here is what I have tried:

```
echo $($(du -sh myFolder) + 1) # command not found: 170M
echo $(`du -sh myFolder` + 1)  # same as above
```

I want to be able to save this to a variable so I can use it in a `dd` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $(($(du -sb myFolder | cut -f1)+1048576))
```

`du -sb` gives a single sumarized result in bytes.

Comment: This gives me the error, "bad math expression: operator expected at '1157680\n40...'"

Comment: @chris13524 edited the answer, a `-s` (sumarize) was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives if you can't use -b as Joao Morais suggested:

```
expr `du -hs myFolder | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d M` + 1

echo $((`du -hs myFolder | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d M` + 1))
```

Comment: This is only going to work if the `-h` (human readable) flag finds a size it wants to represent in MBs.  I have, for example: `du -hs /u6`
`155G    /u6`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
BLOCKSIZE=1048576 du -s myFolder | awk '{print $1+1}'
```

or to put in a variable:

```
mbs=$(BLOCKSIZE=1048576 du -s myFolder | awk '{print $1+1}')
```

Works on Linux, BSD, and OS X (possibly others).